# Xcode - Segue issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue

i'm trying to send a variable from one UITableViewController to another. To be more specific, i'm trying to send the value of a text label (which is located in a custom cell) to a varibale created in the second view controller.

I've written the following... but i dont think it's quite right as the `...preparesegue...` method doesnt fire.

Can someone take a look and let me know where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender tableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CountryToState"]) {
    NSLog(@"TEST");
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSLog(@"%@", path);

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    NSString *countryRef = [[cell ReferenceLabel] text];

    TableViewControllerStates *TVCS = [segue destinationViewController];
    TVCS.receivedReferenceNumber = countryRef;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CountryToState" sender:nil];

}
```

[image]

Comment: Check your cell identifier is set correctly in both the storyboard and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Is the above incorrect?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *cellId = @"CellIdentifier";
    
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    cell.TitleLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"CountryName"];
    cell.ReferenceLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"id"];
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: The above is the method that loads an array into the labels on my tableview.

Comment: You can't create a new  `prepareForSegue` method with your own signature and expect the system to call it.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own questions, just add the extra information to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that method you mentioned is getting called. As I don't see any call to method: `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender tableView:(UITableView *)tableView`.

As I can find right code must look like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CountryToState"]) {
        NSIndexPath *path = (NSIndexPath *) sender;
        NSLog(@"%@", path);

        TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        NSString *countryRef = [[cell ReferenceLabel] text];
        NSLog(@"countryRef = %@", countryRef);

        TableViewControllerStates *TVCS = (TableViewControllerStates *)[segue destinationViewController];
        TVCS.receivedReferenceNumber = countryRef;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CountryToState" sender:indexPath];
}
```

So to summarise long conversation ins short you calling wrong `prepareForSegue` delegate method.

Comment: @Abizern I see him calling, `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CountryToState" sender:nil];` but he is using this delegate `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender tableView:(UITableView *)tableView` I dont's see such delegate in `UIViewController` Class. Am I missing something?

Comment: i could kiss you -- thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out on my own for ages!

Comment: Any time amigo! Happy coding :-).